# what's happened with my php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel, schema, migrate, laravel-artisan

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i
 n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v
 ersion for the right syntax to use near ') on delete cascade on update casc
 ade' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint users_address_id_fo
 reign foreign key (`address_id`) references `address` () on delete cascade
 on update cascade)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i
n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v
ersion for the right syntax to use near ') on delete cascade on update casc
ade' at line 1

migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force] [--path[="..."]] [--pac
kage[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]

```
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users',function($table){
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name',30);
                $table->string('phone',11);
                $table->integer('age');
                $table->string('email',50);
                $table->string('marry_status',10);
                $table->integer('address_id');
                $table->foreign('address_id')->reference('id')->on('address')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
                $table->integer('points_id');
                $table->foreign('points_id')->reference('id')->on('address')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();   
            });
        }
```

php migrate --pretend

```
CreateUsersTable: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(30) not null, `phone` varchar(11) not null, `age` int not null, `email` varchar(50) not null, `marry_status` varchar(10) not null, `address_id` int not null, `points_id` int not null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci

CreateUsersTable: alter table `users` add constraint users_address_id_foreign foreign key (`address_id`) references `address` () on delete cascade on update cascade

CreateUsersTable: alter table `users` add constraint users_points_id_foreign foreign key (`points_id`) references `address` () on delete cascade on update cascade

CreateAddressTable: create table `address` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `users_id` int not null, `name` varchar(30) not null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci

CreatePointsTable: create table `points` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `point` int not null, `users_id` int not null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci
```

i try but i not good

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users',function($table){
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name',30);
                $table->string('phone',11);
                $table->integer('age');
                $table->string('email',50);
                $table->string('marry_status',10);
                $table->integer('address_id');

                $table->integer('points_id');

                $table->timestamps();   
            });
            Schema::table('users',function($table){
                $table->foreign('points_id')->references('id')->on('address')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
                $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('address')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            });

        }
```

Comment: Run `migrate` command with `--pretend` flag and show us the output.

Comment: @anh You have an **edit** link below your question, use it to modify the question and include the output of the command there, don't post that information in the comments.

Comment: Update please your question with this output. It will be much more readable.

Comment: @anh You have to do it in an absolutely separate migration file that has to be after all tables are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in your syntax. You are using `reference()` method, but the right method is `references()`. Fix it and I think everything will be ok.

Comment: @anh This happens because you are trying to create a foreign key for a column of a table that is not yet exist. Look at the `--pretend` output. You are creating 2 foreign keys before you are creating the `address` and `points` tables. Move creating of the keys to another migration and it will work lake a charm.